# FreeNX terminates session immediately after login

Tags: configuration, freenx

I have installed FreeNX Server on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I am using OpenNX (0.16.0725)

The FreeNX session starts with a blank/black screen and an active cursor but then terminates without an error message ~ 15 secs after successful login.

I have tried multiple sugested "fixes" to this problem without any success. (Uncommenting AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_X="-norender",Uncommenting COMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session ubuntu-2d', re-creating an empty .Xauthority file)

I know that FreeNX is no longer under development and that X2Go and other alternatives are available. I have used OpenNX/FreeNX combo with virtually no problems in the past and would like to stay with it at this point.

I am an absolute newbie with the configuration of FreeNX and have very limited linux background.  So patient and generous/robust explanations are appreciated.

Attached are all of the what I think are the relevant config and log files (order as listed below)

**FreeNX Server Files**

```
node-cln.conf -NOTE: all extraneous explanatory comments have been stripped out
nxnode-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.log
nxserver-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.log
session-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.txt

**OpenNX Client Files**
OpenNX-Client-MB-config-cln.nxs
OpenNX-Client-runlog-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.txt
OpenNX-Client-session-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.txt
OpenNX-Client-sshlog-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.txt
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
# node-cln.conf - MB
#-NOTE: all extraneous explanatory comments have been stripped out
# Uncommenting AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_X="-norender" - Did NOT resolve X-abort
# Uncommenting COMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session ubuntu-2d'- Did NOT resolve X abort
#
# NX_LOG_LEVEL=7 has been set => highest level of logging
# SESSION_LOG_CLEAN=0 has been set => session logs not cleaned on termination
#
# SVN: $Id: node.conf.sample 613 2008-09-01 20:42:31Z fabianx $
##############################################################
# General FreeNX directives
##############################################################
#SERVER_NAME="$(hostname)"
#EXTERNAL_PROXY_IP=""
# The port number where local 'sshd' is listening.
#SSHD_PORT=xxxx
##############################################################
# Authentication / Security directives
##############################################################
#ENABLE_USERMODE_AUTHENTICATION="0"
#ENABLE_PASSDB_AUTHENTICATION="0"
#ENABLE_SSH_AUTHENTICATION="1"
#ENABLE_SU_AUTHENTICATION="0"
#ENABLE_USER_DB="0"
#ENABLE_FORCE_ENCRYPTION="0"
#SSHD_CHECK_IP="0"
#ENABLE_SLAVE_MODE="1"
#ENABLE_LOG_FAILED_LOGINS="1"
##############################################################
# Restriction directives
##############################################################
#DISPLAY_BASE=1000
#SESSION_LIMIT=200
#SESSION_USER_LIMIT=200
#DISPLAY_LIMIT=200
#ENABLE_PERSISTENT_SESSION="all"
#DISABLE_PERSISTENT_SESSION=""
#ENABLE_MIRROR_VIA_VNC=1
#ENABLE_DESKTOP_SHARING=1
# General shadowing / mirroring notes:
#ENABLE_SESSION_SHADOWING_AUTHORIZATION=1
#ENABLE_INTERACTIVE_SESSION_SHADOWING=1
#ENABLE_CLIPBOARD="both"
#ENABLE_PULLDOWN_MENU="1"
#COMMAND_STARTKDE="taskset -c 2 -- startkde"
#USE_PROCESSOR_TASKSET=""
#ENABLE_ADVANCED_SESSION_CONTROL="0"
#ENABLE_SHOW_RUNNING_SESSIONS="1"
##############################################################
# Logging directives
##############################################################
# This directives controls the verbosity of the server-wide log.
# 0: No Logging
# 1: Errors
# 2: Warnings
# 3: Important information
# 4: Server - Client communication
# 5: Information
# 6: Debugging information
# 7: stderror of some applications
NX_LOG_LEVEL=7
# By setting this to 0 the nxserver might be a bit faster, but passwords can be found in the log files.
#NX_LOG_SECURE=1
NX_LOGFILE=/var/log/nxserver.log
# The default is to cleanup the directories:=>SESSION_LOG_CLEAN=1
#SESSION_LOG_CLEAN=1
SESSION_LOG_CLEAN=0
#SESSION_HISTORY=2592000
##############################################################
# Forwarding directives
##############################################################
#ENABLE_SERVER_FORWARD="0"
#SERVER_FORWARD_HOST=""
#SERVER_FORWARD_PORT=22
#SERVER_FORWARD_KEY="/usr/NX/share/client.id_dsa.key"
#ENABLE_NOMACHINE_FORWARD_PORT="0"
#NOMACHINE_FORWARD_PORT="22"
#NOMACHINE_SERVER="/usr/NX/bin/nxserver"
#NOMACHINE_NX_HOME_DIR="/usr/NX/home/nx"
# LOAD BALANCING
#LOAD_BALANCE_SERVERS=""
#LOAD_BALANCE_ALGORITHM="random"
#ENABLE_LOAD_BALANCE_PREFERENCE="0"
##############################################################
# Services directives
##############################################################
#ENABLE_ESD_PRELOAD="0"
#ESD_BIN_PRELOAD="esddsp"
#ENABLE_ARTSD_PRELOAD="0"
#ARTSD_BIN_PRELOAD="artsdsp"
#ENABLE_KDE_CUPS="1"
#ENABLE_KDE_CUPS_DYNAMIC="0"
#KDE_PRINTRC="$KDEHOME/share/config/kdeprintrc"
#ENABLE_CUPS_SERVER_EXPORT="1"
#ENABLE_CUPS_SEAMLESS="0"
#CUPS_SEAMLESS_DELAY="10"
#ENABLE_FOOMATIC="1"
#COMMAND_FOOMATIC="/usr/bin/foomatic-ppdfile"
#CUPS_BACKEND="/usr/lib/cups/backend"
#CUPS_IPP_BACKEND="$CUPS_BACKEND/ipp"
#CUPS_DEFAULT_SOCK="/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
#CUPS_ETC="/etc/cups"
#SAMBA_MOUNT_SHARE_PROTOCOL="both"
#ENABLE_SAMBA_PRELOAD="0"
#ENABLE_SOURCE_BASH_PROFILE="1"
##############################################################
# Path directives
##############################################################
#SET_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="0"
#DEFAULT_X_WM=""
#KILL_DEFAULT_X_WM="1"
#USER_X_STARTUP_SCRIPT=.Xclients
#DEFAULT_X_SESSION=/etc/X11/Xsession
#BOOTSTRAP_X_SESSION="0"
#COMMAND_START_KDE='startkde'
#COMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session gnome-fallback'
COMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session ubuntu-2d'
#COMMAND_START_CDE='xfce4-session'
#COMMAND_XTERM=xterm
#COMMAND_XAUTH=/usr/bin/xauth
#COMMAND_SMBMOUNT=smbmount
#COMMAND_SMBUMOUNT=smbumount
#COMMAND_SMBMOUNT_CIFS=/sbin/mount.cifs
#COMMAND_SMBUMOUNT_CIFS=/sbin/umount.cifs
#COMMAND_NETCAT=netcat
#COMMAND_SSH=ssh
#COMMAND_SSH_KEYGEN=ssh-keygen
#COMMAND_CUPSD=/usr/sbin/cupsd
#COMMAND_MD5SUM="openssl md5"
#COMMAND_RDESKTOP=rdesktop
#COMMAND_VNCVIEWER=vncviewer
#COMMAND_VNCPASSWD="$PATH_BIN/nxpasswd"
#COMMAND_X11VNC=x11vnc
#COMMAND_TASKSET=taskset
##############################################################
# Misc directives
##############################################################
#ENABLE_1_5_0_BACKEND="0"
#ENABLE_AUTORECONNECT="0"
#ENABLE_AUTORECONNECT_BEFORE_140="1"
#EXPORT_USERIP="0"
#EXPORT_SESSIONID="1"
#NODE_AUTOSTART=""
#ENABLE_ROOTLESS_MODE="1"
#ENABLE_USESSION="1"
#COMMAND_SESSREG="sessreg"
#AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_RFB=""
#AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_RDP=""
#AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_X="-nolisten tcp"
AGENT_EXTRA_OPTIONS_X="-norender"
#AGENT_STARTUP_TIMEOUT="60"
#AGENT_FONT_SERVER=""
#PROXY_TCP_NODELAY=""
#PROXY_EXTRA_OPTIONS=""
#ENABLE_EXTERNAL_NXDESKTOP="1"
#ENABLE_EXTERNAL_NXDESKTOP_KEYBOARD="1"
#ENABLE_EXTERNAL_NXVIEWER="1"

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
nxnode-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.log
20.06 12:51:21 PM: startsession (3906): starting with args ""
20.06 12:51:21 PM: startsession (3906): write xauth script file
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): source bash profile
20.06 12:51:21 PM: startsession (3906): call 'node_start_agent'
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): env start XDG_SESSION_ID=2
NX_CLIENT=/usr/lib/nx/nxdialog
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=49fdacf2210b6bb5fca9abdc54d708d0-1434822679.383113-836300376
SSH_CLIENT=127.0.0.1 48680 xxxx
USER=d
NXSESSIONID=MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991
MAIL=/var/mail/d
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
SHADOW_XAUTHORITY=/home/d/.nx/C-MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991/authority
PWD=/home/d
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SLAVE_PID=3598
SHLVL=3
HOME=/home/d
LOGNAME=d
SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 48680 127.0.0.1 xxxx
DISPLAY=nx/nx,options=/home/d/.nx/C-MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991/options:2000
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XAUTHORITY=/home/d/.nx/C-MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991/authority
_=/usr/bin/env
20.06 12:51:21 PM: startsession (3906): generate "/home/d/.nx/C-MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991/options"
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_applications (3906): starting
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_monitor (3906): call 'node_start_monitor_2_0_0 ""'
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_applications (3906): source bash profile
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_monitor (3906): staring
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_applications (3906): source profile
20.06 12:51:21 PM: startsession (3906): call 'node_start_applications'
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): Start nxagent by command: '/usr/bin/nxagent -persistent -D -name "NX - d@MB:2000 - MB (GPL Edition)" -options "/home/d/.nx/C-MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991/options"   -norender :2000'
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): NXAgent session type
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_applications (3906): DISPLAY is 2000
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): starting
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): env end
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_monitor_2_0_0 (3906): starting
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): Wait for NODE_AGENT_PID (4199)
20.06 12:51:21 PM: node_start_agent (3906): source profile
20.06 12:51:24 PM: node_find_application (3906): starting with args "unix-gnome"
20.06 12:51:24 PM: node_find_application (3906): end
20.06 12:51:24 PM: node_find_application (3906): return NODE_STARTX="gnome-session --session ubuntu-2d"
20.06 12:51:24 PM: node_start_applications (3906): Got NODE_APPLICATION is "gnome-session --session ubuntu-2d"
20.06 12:51:24 PM: node_start_applications (3906): Waiting for NODE_APP_PID
20.06 12:51:24 PM: node_start_applications (3906): Starting NODE_APPLICATION with /etc/nxserver/Xsession
20.06 12:51:24 PM: node_start_applications (3906): Start successful. NODE_APP_PID=4488
20.06 12:51:30 PM: node_start_applications (3906): Clean pids/apps/4488
20.06 12:51:30 PM: node_start_applications (3906): NODE_APP_PID finished
20.06 12:51:35 PM: node_start_applications (3906): Call node_terminate_agent for non-rootless or virtualdesktop session type
20.06 12:51:35 PM: node_start_applications (3906): Call 'node_terminate_agent "MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991"'
20.06 12:51:35 PM: node_terminate_agent (3906): starting
20.06 12:51:35 PM: node_terminate_agent (3906): killing NODE_AGENT_PID
20.06 12:51:35 PM: node_start_applications (3906): end
20.06 12:51:35 PM: node_terminate_agent (3906): end
20.06 12:51:35 PM: node_terminate_agent (3906): process list for 'nxagent' empty
20.06 12:51:36 PM: node_start_monitor_2_0_0 (3906): end

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
nxserver-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.log from nxserver.log
new session:nxserver-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991

-- NX SERVER START: -c /usr/lib/nx/nxserver - ORIG_COMMAND=
-- NX SERVER START:  - ORIG_COMMAND=
Info: Using fds #4 and #3 for communication with nxnode.
HELLO NXSERVER - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.5.0)
NX> 105 hello NXCLIENT - Version 3.2.0
NX> 134 Accepted protocol: 3.2.0
NX> 105 SET SHELL_MODE SHELL
NX> 105 SET AUTH_MODE PASSWORD
NX> 105 login
NX> 101 User: d
NX> 102 Password: 
Info: Auth method: ssh d@127.0.0.1's password:
NX> 1000 NXNODE - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.5.0)
NX> 716 Slave mode started successfully.
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
nxnode_reader: NX> 1000 NXNODE - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.5.0)
nxnode_reader: NX> 716 finished
nxnode_reader: NX> 1001 Bye.
NX> 103 Welcome to: MB user: d
NX> 105 listsession --user="d" --status="suspended,running" --type="unix-gnome" --geometry="1440x900x24+render"
NX> 127 Sessions list of user 'd' for reconnect:
Display Type             Session ID                       Options  Depth Screen         Status      Session Name
------- ---------------- -------------------------------- -------- ----- -------------- ----------- ------------------------
NX> 148 Server capacity: not reached for user: d
NX> 105 startsession --session="MB" --type="unix-gnome" --cache="8M" --images="32M" --link="lan" --geometry="1440x852" --screeninfo="1440x900x24+render" --keyboard="pc105/us" --backingstore="1" --encryption="1" --render="1" --composite="1" --shmem="1" --shpix="1" --samba="0" --cups="0" --nodelay="1" --defer="0" --client="linux" --media="0" --strict="0" --aux="1" 
Info: Using /etc/nxserver/nxacl to change session parameters or deny session.
&session=MB&type=unix-gnome&cache=8M&images=32M&link=lan&geometry=1440x852&screeninfo=1440x900x24+render&keyboard=pc105/us&backingstore=1&encryption=1&render=1&composite=1&shmem=1&shpix=1&samba=0&cups=0&nodelay=1&defer=0&client=linux&media=0&strict=0&aux=1&clientproto=3.2.0&login_method=SSH&user=d&userip=192.168.1.101&uniqueid=D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991&display=2000&host=127.0.0.1 
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
nxnode_reader: NX> 1000 NXNODE - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.5.0)
NX> 1000 NXNODE - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.5.0)
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 1000 NXNODE - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.5.0)
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
nxnode_reader: NX> 700 Session id: MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991
nxnode_reader: NX> 705 Session display: 2000
nxnode_reader: NX> 703 Session type: unix-gnome
nxnode_reader: NX> 701 Proxy cookie: c6eff819fdac0c16472ca5055e227d91
nxnode_reader: NX> 702 Proxy IP: 127.0.1.1
nxnode_reader: NX> 706 Agent cookie: c6eff819fdac0c16472ca5055e227d91
nxnode_reader: NX> 704 Session cache: unix-gnome
nxnode_reader: NX> 707 SSL tunneling: 1
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 700 Session id: MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991
NX> 700 Session id: MB-2000-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991
NX> 705 Session display: 2000
NX> 703 Session type: unix-gnome
NX> 701 Proxy cookie: c6eff819fdac0c16472ca5055e227d91
NX> 702 Proxy IP: 127.0.1.1
NX> 706 Agent cookie: c6eff819fdac0c16472ca5055e227d91
NX> 704 Session cache: unix-gnome
NX> 707 SSL tunneling: 1
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 705 Session display: 2000
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 703 Session type: unix-gnome
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 701 Proxy cookie: c6eff819fdac0c16472ca5055e227d91
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 702 Proxy IP: 127.0.1.1
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 706 Agent cookie: c6eff819fdac0c16472ca5055e227d91
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 704 Session cache: unix-gnome
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 707 SSL tunneling: 1
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
nxnode_reader: NX> 1009 Session status: starting
NX> 1009 Session status: starting
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 1009 Session status: starting
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
nxnode_reader: NX> 710 Session status: running
nxnode_reader: NX> 1002 Commit
nxnode_reader: NX> 1006 Session status: running
NX> 710 Session status: running
NX> 1002 Commit
NX> 1006 Session status: running
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 710 Session status: running
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 1002 Commit
session_status D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991 Running
NX> 105 server_nxnode_echo: NX> 1006 Session status: running
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
.
.
.
nxnode_reader: -i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
bye
Bye
NX> 999 Bye
nxnode_reader: NX> 1009 Session status: terminating
NX> 1009 Session status: terminating
session_status D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991 Terminating
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 1009 Session status: terminating
Info: Closing connection to slave with pid 3549.
nxnode_reader: 1001 Bye.
1001 Bye.
nxnode_reader: NX> 1006 Session status: closed
NX> 1006 Session status: closed
session_close D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 1006 Session status: closed
nxnode_reader: NX> 1001 Bye.
NX> 1001 Bye.
server_nxnode_echo: NX> 1001 Bye.
Info: Closing connection to slave with pid 3549.

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
session-D57CCA9661E221DF169845886CBA6991-cln.txt
NXAGENT - Version 3.5.0
Copyright (C) 2001, 2011 NoMachine.
See http://www.nomachine.com/ for more information.
Info: Agent running with pid '4199'.
Session: Starting session at 'Sat Jun 20 12:51:21 2015'.
Info: Proxy running in server mode with pid '4199'.
Info: Waiting for connection from '127.0.0.1' on port '6000'.
Info: Accepted connection from '127.0.0.1'.
Info: Connection with remote proxy completed.
Info: Using LAN link parameters 1536/24/1/0.
Info: Using agent parameters 5000/0/50/0/0.
Info: Using pack method 'adaptive-9' with session 'gnome'.
Info: Using product 'LFE/None/LFEN/None'.
Info: Not using NX delta compression.
Info: Not using ZLIB data compression.
Info: Not using ZLIB stream compression.
Info: Not using a persistent cache.
Info: Listening to X11 connections on display ':2000'.
Info: Listening to auxiliary X11 connections on port '10000'.
Info: Established X client connection.
Info: Using shared memory parameters 1/1/1/2048K.
Info: Not using local device configuration changes.
InitOutput: Locale en_US.UTF-8 not supported by X
InitOutput: cannot set locale modifiers.
nxagentXkbGetRules: WARNING! Failed to stat file [/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/xkb/rules/xorg]: Unknown error -1.
keyboard file created
SessionPath not defined
Session: Session started at 'Sat Jun 20 12:51:24 2015'.
Session: Terminating session at 'Sat Jun 20 12:51:35 2015'.
Info: Waiting the cleanup timeout to complete.
Session: Session terminated at 'Sat Jun 20 12:51:36 2015'.
e-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[4488]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session[4488]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

OpenNX Client Files: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11754269/